# For the .com TLD, is there any known change tracking for WhoIs information?

Tags: domain-name-system, whois, privacy

A client exposed information regarding what will become a controversial website in the domain WhoIs after she purchased it from auction.

Is there any whois cache that will detect, save, and share the old whois information for that domain, after it has changed?

(It's a website to provide birth control in countries where it is banned, and she may receive death threats for the information shared on it.  Obviously something she wishes to avoid.)

Comment: This kind of scenario is one of the reasons why I built https://GWhois.org . People should be able to perform a whois lookup without having to worry about the information being saved or later being held for ransom. For example, who.is charges you $29.99 to remove your information! (Which is why if you are not sure what your domain is showing on the whois data you should NOT use who.is to check) You can learn more about GWhois.org here: http://blog.gwhois.org/updates/security-and-protecting-your-privacy/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.domaintools.com/research/whois-history/

They supposedly keep track of that data.  I've never used their service, but you can see from sample reports what the data would look like.  Or you can have your client purchase their domain's WHOIS history and see if the data she's wishing to hide is in there or not.

Answer (score 1):

http://who.is/ has a history of records in the tab called History after you do a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

The domaintools WHOIS history is the one everyone uses. It's not perfect, they do snapshots. I agree with the suggestion that she pay for a history of the domain in question to see what they have. It's about $50, and that's what most people womdering about its history are likely to try.

There's a history tab at who.is, but precious little history behind it.  I tried some domains that have been live for a decade and it had something.

Note that since the domaintools history requires money, people are unlikely to stumble across anything by accident.